# How to make a text look "clickable" in mobile applications?

Tags: android

I first made the clickable text **bold** and rest all normal

Then the one who tested said he can't make out the clickable text.

I changed the color to blue, so now its much better but he even wanted me to underline it.

Now it looks like a link on web apps.

What is the UI usually used for clickable texts?

[image]

the blue, underlines text is clickable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conventions are your friend (one of the reasons I hate the phrase "think outside the box"... think outside the box when coming up with a product or idea, think inside while attempting to make something usable).

Colored text is a convention for click on the web in general, so that works, but if you want it to continue looking like a mobile app and not a website, think about using a button or "pill" link with a call to action.

Barring that, I'd also look at a slight redesign of your area. I don't know what it looks like with multiple listings, but i'd suggest sectioning out each item and making the entire area clickable with a ">" arrow to suggest clickability.

A few options there.

Comment: i cant keep the whole list a clickable because, sometimes 2 different clicks might be there on the same list item. like say the 1st blue line and also the discount is clickable. But i didnt get you. What is your final suggestion?? carry on with as it is? i cant use button, i mean i need to use Text only

Comment: The way it is in the screenshot WORKS, doesn't mean it's optimal. The web convention gets the job done, but at that point it's always going to feel like a webapp shoe-horned onto a mobile device. Usability-wise the blue links will be fine, but your app will lose some of that mobile shine ;)

Comment: I think show right arrow will feel clickable

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in a browser or other environment that the user feels comfortable clicking links in, you must try *even harder* to delineate links or clickable elements. Blue with an underline is the standard styling for links and the user will immediate recognise them as such - remember "don't make me think!".

Comment: But in some android applications if something is implemented in Apple style. people say "This app isn't following Google UI patterns" or "Doesn't look like a native UI". Here it looks more like a Web URL link.

Comment: I suppose more detail is required to answer this question fully. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: yes i added it to the question